# Convergence of $\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{1}{e^x+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm trying to prove the convergence of

$$\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{1}{e^x+1}dx$$

Any suggestion or hint for how to deal with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Such an integral is the limit of $\int_0^t$ as $t\to\infty$. And this integrand is less than $e^{-x}$ on $[0,t]$.

Comment: I feel like you can work into this exp'=exp (or put more provocatively each tail of the exponential is similar).

Comment: Show that it is bounded by $ \ln 2$.

Comment: @copper.hat Nice hint! The integral is convergent and the value is in fact $\ln 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you compare the integrand to $\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ because we know how to integrate that. We also know that it is always greater than $0$, so use the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the substitute $e^x+1=t$. Then your integral becomes $\displaystyle \int_2^{\infty}\frac{1}{t(t-1)}dt.$

For $t>2$, $t^2>2t$. Hence, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{t(t-1)}=\frac{1}{t^2-t}\leq \frac{1}{t^2-t^2/2}=\frac{2}{t^2}.$

$\displaystyle \int_2^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2}dt $ converges since $2>1$. So by comparison test, the integral converges.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the integral as
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^n \frac{1}{1+e^x} dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^n \left(1- \frac{e^x}{1+e^x}\right) dx
\end{equation}

Now, evaluate the integral above to obtain 
\begin{equation}
n - \ln(1+e^n) + \ln2 = \ln \left( \frac{e^n}{1+e^n}\right) + \ln2
\end{equation}

Now, send $n \to \infty$ and use the continuity of $t \mapsto \ln(t)$ to push the limit inside, you will immediately obtain the value of integral as $\ln2$.

Answer (score -2):

It is sufficient to show that the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ of $\exp (-x)$ converges. But this is merely that the integral from - $\infty$ to $0$ of $\exp(x) $converges. That is, $\exp(x)$ from $-\infty$ to $0$ converges, which is just $1-0=1$.

Comment: Until you use LaTeX syntax, your answers will likely be downvoted by some users.

Comment: @6005 They know. They just refuse.